# Leipzig glossaries in each chapter of the book

Tags: glossaries

I want leipzig.sty to output separate glossaries for each chapter in a book:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}
\newleipzig{ant}{ant}{anterior}

\Top{} \Ant{}
\printglossaries

\chapter{2}
\newleipzig{ant}{ant}{antecedent}

\Top{} \Ant{}
\printglossaries
```

For example in this code, I want two glossaries: "topic" and "anterior" for ch.1, and "topic" and "antecedent" for ch.2.

How can I get this?

Thank you!